# React - state not changing for value select in dropdown?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have two drop downs. The first one lists the "make" of vehicles, the other "models". The data of the "Make" drop down is loaded when the page is loaded. Depending on the selection of this drop down, the "Model" drop down is populated.

When I click the "Make" dropdown, the "handleMakeDropDown" is called and the text sucuessfully changes for the "Make" drop down. However, when I call console.log and print out dropDownMakeText, the text isn't updating. This is confusing because the text of the drop down is changing, which relies on dropDownMakeText, but when I print it to the console it isn't changed? I'm not sure why this is happening? It seems like the state and value for dropDownMakeText is changing in one place but not the other?

```
const [filterData, setFilterData] = useState(null) //this gets set by an api call when page loads
const[dropDownMakeText, setDropdownText] = useState("Make")
const[dropDownModelText, setDropdownModelText] = useState("Model")

function getAllMakes(){    
  if(filterData){      
    const keys = Object.keys(filterData.carFilterDetails);      
    return (
  
  <ul className="....">
    {
     keys.map(x=>          
        {return(
        <li key={x}>
          <a href="#" onClick={() => handleMakeDropDown(x)} className="...">{x}</a>
        </li>)}
        )
      }
  </ul>
   )
  }
}


function handleMakeDropDown(selection: string){   
  setDropdownText(selection)        
  const modelList = getAllModels(selection)    
  console.log("this is dropDownMakeText in handleMake", dropDownMakeText) //this prints out "Make"
  .....
}

function getAllModels(makeSelection: string){
 console.log("this is dropDownMakeText in handleModel", dropDownMakeText) //this prints out "Make"
  const models = filterData.carFilterDetails[makeSelection];    
  return (      
    <ul className=... aria-labelledby="dropdownMakeButton">
    {
     models.map(x=>          
        {return(
        <li key={x.model}>
        <a href="#" onClick={() => handleModelDropDown(x.model)} className=...>{x.model}</a>
      </li>)}
      )
    }
</ul>)
}

return (
 ....
 <button id="dropdownMakeButton" data-dropdown-toggle="dropdownMakes" type="button"> {dropDownMakeText}</button>//changes based on what selection I make
```

{getAllMakes()}
             
     ....
     )

[image]

[image]

[image]